# Flexible search query using three tables

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have three tables Order,Customer,Address.

Edited :

I want to fetch all customer's who are registeretd with website.
       If the customer has placed any order's i want to fetch the latest order from list of order's,
       If customer has not placed any order then i want to put the field as blank as shown in below table

```
For eg :

       Customer_Name   Email ID   Country   Phone   Latest_Order_Code
       A               xxxx        xxxx     x       1234 

       B               yyyy        yyyy     y

       C               ffff        tttt     l       3456

       D               zzzz        iiii     o
```

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: can you please have a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71546100/sap-hybris-how-to-display-specific-products-at-top-results-after-search

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refer to below query, where I have only fetch order code and Customer name. You can write more join and select fields based on your requirement.

```
select {o.code} as orderCode,
       {c.name} as name,
       {a.cellphone} as cellphone

from   {order as o 
        join Customer as c on {c.pk} = {o.user} 
        join Address as a on {o.deliveryaddress} = {a.pk}
       } 

       where {o.code} in ({{select max({code}) from {order} group by {user}}})
```

---

### Update: Fetch all registered customers and their last order information

```
select t1.name, t2.orderCode, t2.cellphone

from 

({{
  select {pk} as userPk, {name} as name from {Customer}
}}) as t1

LEFT JOIN

({{
    select 
       {o.code} as orderCode,
       {o.user} as user,
       {a.cellphone} as cellphone

from   {order as o 
        join Address as a on {o.deliveryaddress} = {a.pk}
       } 

       where {o.code} in ({{select max({code}) from {order} group by {user}}})
}}) as t2

on t2.user = t1.userPk
```

---

### Detail post [how to write complex flexible search query join using the dynamic tables?](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/04/complex-query-join-hybris-flexible-search.html)

Comment: How can i join three tables with this approach?i want to join address table as well?

Comment: Refer the way I join customer, you can add one more join (Address). I will update my post soon

Comment: Can we get list with all registered customers with the date of the last order, in case the customer doesn’t have an order, this option must be blank?

Comment: I didn't get you. Could you elaborate more.

Comment: I want to fetch all customer's who are registeretd with website.
    If the customer has placed any order's i want to fetch the latest order from list of order's,
    If customer has not placed any order then i want to put the field as blank as shown in table @HybrisFreelance Pls check my above edited post

Comment: You should ask the new question, as it seems you changed it completely. Anyway I will update my answer!!

Comment: Find my updated answer, `select {pk} as userPk, {name} as name from {Customer}` here you can add more fields which you want and finally select it as I did for `t1.name`. Hope this help!!

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help..One  last question..Can i add country as well for this above query?

Comment: Yes, you can simply have more join and get the data you want. I'm glad this helps you. you can mark this as answered !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168207/discussion-between-user2413-and-hybrisfreelance).